# why eclipse doesn't come with bundled svn client

Tags: eclipse, svn, cvs, subclipse, subversive

[Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org) is deployed with [CVS client plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-cvs/) by default. Why there are no [svn](https://subversion.apache.org/) source control clients that are bundled also by default?

Comment: <insert comment about git that instigates holy war here>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a [discussion](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=284552)  that sheds some light on potential problems integrating the various svn plug-ins that exist for eclipse.

From Tigris' [Status of Eclipse SVN Proposal](http://subclipse.tigris.org/eclipse-proposal.html) :

> One final factor in this decision [to
>   withdraw the proposal] was licensing.
>   Any Subversion plug-in is going to
>   depend on either Subversion's JavaHL
>   library or the SVNKit pure Java
>   library. SVNKit's license was rejected
>   by Eclipse, and in the case of
>   Subversion they were planning to
>   review all the code before allowing us
>   to use the library. Subversion has
>   dependencies on libraries like Neon
>   and BDB that have licenses that are
>   not typically accepted by Eclipse. So
>   we had some question as to whether we
>   would be able to include JavaHL or
>   SVNKit with our plug-in. Again, maybe
>   this will turn out to not be an issue
>   for Subversive.

So various licensing problems appears to be the crux of including an existing svn plug-in by default.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has something to do with the fact that [the source code for Eclipse itself is still stored in CVS](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto).

Comment: @ohadshai: apparently there are many projects under the "eclipse" umbrella. Some of these are in CVS, others in SVN. The Eclipse IDE project is in CVS.